# A personalized email algorithm

Tags: email, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I've been delving into a lot of recommendation algorithms lately (collaborative filtering mostly) and I've found quite a lot of answers on recommending an item based on either a specific user or item (which is part of what I want to do, so that works out). I also want to sent out somewhat-personalized emails, meaning given an email with a certain set of products, pick a set of users to send out the email to.

What would be the best way/algorithm to go about doing this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming problem

Answer (score 1):

For this, you simply turn around the usual collaborative filtering process: instead of recommending items to users, you recommend users to items. You are therefore guessing which users will most like a given item.

Just feed in product IDs as "user IDs", and your real user IDs as "item IDs" into a collaborative filtering system like Apache Mahout. It will recommend users ("items") that would be best for any given email ("user").

Of course you still need input data. Perhaps you have collected a past history of which users have rated or bought or viewed products. That is still your input.